# Is there a common way to sync/pull a remote repository data from server regularly on the Android MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, mvvm

Please see my simple scenario and let me know if there is a common way on the android MVVM architecture.

1. I'm going to make simple remote repository code which would get a data(ex. temperature) from weather server via HTTP request(RESTful API).
2. The data would not be presented to UI unless the user wants refresh but the data, temperature, it should be up-to-dated and stored with DateTime into local(It'll be used to calculate how much the temperature was going up/down)

Maybe, I could make a second step's one by using doInBackground with timer so that it can gather the  temperature data in the background task regularly.

But I'm not sure it's right way or not.

What I really want to know is that if there is any other common way or recommended way by google or architect.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a recommended approach to this by using android architecture components linked [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture); If you use MVVM pattern along with livedata and Room and repository structure (all explained in detail in the link by Google itself!)  Go through this also some samples from google codelabs also there are numerous videos as well can be found on this in Youtube that will help you a great deal.
As for more ideas, please post some codes/current status what are you doing to get your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
Actually I already have checked and seen google's guide but I haven't found what exactly I want to know.
How to poll data via HTTP GET regularly inside the repository layer, it's what I want to know.